# Espresso test on a Capacitor app shows "Could not launch intent Intent within 45 seconds"

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-espresso, capacitor

I'm trying to implement a Espresso test with a Capacitor app. The test looks like this:

```
package com.getcapacitor.myapp;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.test.espresso.web.webdriver.DriverAtoms;
import androidx.test.espresso.web.webdriver.Locator;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import ekt.moveus.applikate.MainActivity;

import static androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web.onWebView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.web.webdriver.DriverAtoms.clearElement;
import static androidx.test.espresso.web.webdriver.DriverAtoms.findElement;
import static androidx.test.espresso.web.webdriver.DriverAtoms.webClick;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(
    MainActivity.class, false, true) {
    @Override
    protected void afterActivityLaunched() {}
  };

  private final static String USER_EMAIL = "email@gmail.com";
  private final static String USER_PASS = "password";

  @Test
  public void typeTextInInput_clickButton_SubmitsForm() {
    Intent webFormIntent = new Intent();
    mActivityRule.launchActivity(webFormIntent);
    onWebView()
      .withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME, "ion-input-1"))
      .perform(clearElement())
      .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys(USER_EMAIL))

      .withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME, "ion-input-0"))
      .perform(clearElement())
      .perform(DriverAtoms.webKeys(USER_PASS))

      .withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME, "ion-input"))
      .perform(webClick());
  }
}
```

But when I run the test case I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=ekt.moveus.applikate/.MainActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1594199984877 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1594200024655. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:481)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:358)
at com.getcapacitor.myapp.ExampleInstrumentedTest.typeTextInInput_clickButton_SubmitsForm(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:44)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2209)
```

As far as I know and after reading some questions and tutorials, it can be caused by an animation (I´ve disabled them on the emulator), a constant redrawing of some component or a custom view. Since Capacitor works under the hood, I don't really know what's causing the issue.

Anyone faced this? How can I correctly implement an Espresso test case with a Capacitor App?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what a "Capacitor app" is (is it something all Android devs are supposed to know?) -- but anyway, your problem may be that you're launching the activity twice. First you set up the rule to start the activity right away (third param = true), and then in the test, you explicitly launch the activity again. Set the third param to `false` and it'll most likely help.

Comment: I see different packages for the `MainActivity` class and the test code, is `ekt.moveus.applikate` part of the Android Studio project?

Comment: @ahasbini that has nothing to do with the problem, it's just how the Capacitor App works.

Comment: @gosr I'll try what you told. Capacitor is an hybrid app framework just like Cordova or Phonegap. Will tell you if it works.

Comment: @axierjhtjz any luck? Also, the bounty seems to have ended.

Comment: @gosr your answers seems to be right, just post it and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @axierjhtjz done. Would be cool if you could re-enable the bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're launching the activity twice. First you set up the rule to start the activity right away (by having the third parameter as `true` in `new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class, false, true)`, and then in the test, you explicitly launch the activity again (by doing `mActivityRule.launchActivity(webFormIntent);`).

Set the third param to `false` instead.